# How can I get records for the last 24 hours?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

My code looks like:-

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();

String currentDateTimeString = df.format(new Date());

Date today = df.parse(currentDateTimeString);

Date previous_date = new Date(today.getTime()-(24 * 3600000));


cursor = db.rawQuery(" select * from Table_Name where Date > " + previous_date ,null);
```

The values for today, previous_date and next_date are correct but the query fails to execute and throws an exception. Any kind of help will be great.

Comment: Use between keyword insted of > or <

Comment: Please show the actual SQL statement that is ultimately created

Comment: -1 for not posting the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String pDate = dateFormat.format(previous_date);
String nDate = dateFormat.format(next_date);

cursor = db.query(true, TABLE_name, new String[] { //there your all columns name// }, "Date BETWEEN ?
              AND ?" , new String[]{pDate,nDate}, null, null, null,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL:

```
   SELECT  * FROM    tblnm
   WHERE   datefield >= SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

In SQL Server:

```
SELECT  * FROM    tblnm
 WHERE   datefield >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

what on earth is this supposed to do ?

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
String currentDateTimeString = df.format(new Date());
Date today = df.parse(currentDateTimeString);
Date previous_date = new Date(today.getTime()-(24 * 3600000));
```

If i sum this up, you create a formatter, then a string for right now date, then a date based on parsing that string, then removing some number of millis to create yet another date ?

use this :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY, -1);
Date yesterday = cal.getTime();
```

That's one.

secondly, why would you use rawQuery ? `query` is a much better one, mostly because it makes the argument transformation for you.

if you observe your query string, you'll see that you date is not escaped, not formatted properly ...

Use Sardor Dushamov's solution